# How to resize image of product view page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-resizing

I want to resize product view gallery image. I want to **resize main product image to 500X500 size**?

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento uses the file called view.xml which is maintained at the theme level of the application.

So for example, if you are using the default theme luma you should find the view.xml under vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml

In this file, you would see  node inside the  node.

The dimension of the images is maintained here under the  node.

The id attribute value of the  node is referenced in the code base.

```
        <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>560</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>560</height>
        </image>
```

You can define your custom view.xml in your theme and define width & height as per your requirement.

> In case of changing/overwriting the values of the view.xml file you
>   need to completely copy the entire view.xml file to your custom theme
>   and change the values.
>
> view.xml does not have a node value fallback system, means if a value
>   of a node is not present in you custom theme's view.xml it will not
>   fallback to its parent theme's view.xml value, that's why entire file
>   needs to be copied.

Once the values changes have been done, you will have to run

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

This will regenerate the new image sizes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'm just concerned about your citation regarding  overriding view.xml vs extending which is according to you not possible, but in my case, just putting the modified values, kept the parent theme (luma) untouched values, so extending is possible. is it an old issue that was corrected ? can you link the citation ? Best regards and again thank you !