# How to resize pictures from list page on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, image, image-resizing

I tried to set the product pictures from category page to 800x800 px and i can't.

Be default the picutres size is `270x270 px`;
I changed in `view.xml` the values for this fields into `800x800` px but nothing happend.

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>800</width>
                <height>800</height>
            </image>
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>800</width>
                <height>800</height>
            </image>
```

Does anyone know how can i do this?

Comment: have you flush all cache? check in pub/media/catalog/product/.... if the folder 800x800 is created (note: my default size are 240x300)

Comment: yes. i flush all the cache.if i am looking in the path that you said, the folder 800x800 is not there

Comment: try to flush pub/media/catalog/product/cache/, then browse your site and watch which product images are recreated.

Comment: rigjht now. i see in cache that i have 2 folder. first one is  270 and the second one is 800x800

Comment: but after flush the cache and go incognito, when i inspect the img the size is 270x270. doyou have any idea why?

Comment: the new images 800x800 are created this is good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68808/discussion-between-alin-lupoiu-and-luca-s).

Comment: maybe you have 2 xml tag category_page_grid/category_page_list?

Comment: i open the chat discussion

Comment: sorry but i'm not using to private support. your images are correctly created so the issue isn't in the xml (check if you have the tag both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After make change in size value . you need to run below command

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

This will regenerate the new image sizes. you can take as [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201013/how-to-resize-image-of-product-view-page-in-magento-2/201014#201014) this answer.

> In case of changing/overwriting the values of the view.xml file you
>   need to completely copy the entire view.xml file to your custom theme
>   and change the values.
>
> view.xml does not have a node value fallback system, means if a value of 
>   a node is not present in you custom theme's view.xml it will
>   not fallback to its parent theme's view.xml value, that's why entire
>   file needs to be copied.