# Magento 2 resize image product details page

Tags: magento2

How to resize image of product details page in Magento 2?

http://solivr.mobilegiz.com/tunique-noire-brodee-396.html

Comment: I want to do keep frame false on this. Can I do this in view.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses the file called view.xml which is maintained at the theme level of the application.

So for example, if you are using the default theme luma you should find the view.xml under vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml

In this file, you would see node inside the node.

The dimension of the images is maintained here under the node.

The id attribute value of the node is referenced in the code base.

```
    <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>560</height>
    </image>
    <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>560</height>
    </image>
```

You can define your custom view.xml in your theme and define width & height as per your requirement.

> In case of changing/overwriting the values of the view.xml file you
>   need to completely copy the entire view.xml file to your custom theme
>   and change the values.
>
> view.xml does not have a node value fallback system, means if a value
>   of a node is not present in your custom theme's view.xml it will not
>   fallback to its parent theme's view.xml value, that's why the entire file
>   needs to be copied.

Once the values changes have been done, you will have to run

> php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

This will regenerate the new image sizes.

You can take reference this answer [How to resize image of product view page in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201013/how-to-resize-image-of-product-view-page-in-magento-2/201014#201014)

Comment: If its use full, Accept it so others can also use for reference.

Comment: i check and inform you

Comment: not working now so Magento 2 Not Building Product Thumbnails Cache

Comment: Are you checking on local server or production ?

Comment: Why is there a separate `product_page_main_image` and `product_page_main_image_default` and not just 1 size? I don't see the added value of the `_default` variation. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit *vendor\theme\etc\view.xml*. Attributes for product page images are:

```
product_page_image_medium

product_page_image_medium_no_frame

product_page_main_image

product_page_main_image_default
```

Comment: but issue is Magento 2 Not Building Product Thumbnails Cache

Comment: Run bin/magento deploy:mode:set production