# How magento 2.3 generates swatch images?

Tags: magento2.3, swatches, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I want to resize default generated swatch images but upon doing that swatch images get blurred. So my question is, how to resize Magento swatch so that it will look nice? I have tried modifying background-size in `swatch-renderer.js` from `initial` to  `50% 50% !important`. Here is the code for your reference from `swatch-renderer.js`

```
if (type === 2) {
      // Image
      $image.css({
           'background': 'url("' + thumb + '") no-repeat center', 
            //Background case
            // changed background-size from initial to 50% 50% !important
           'background-size': '50% 50% !important'
     });
    $image.show();
}
```

Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In advance..!

Comment: You can do this using view.xml file, Refer this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201013/how-to-resize-image-of-product-view-page-in-magento-2

Comment: I want to resize swatch images not product images, above link is all about modifying product images. @SanjayGohil and I don't see anything related to swatch images in view.xml.

Comment: You will find "swatches" images resize related code inside view.xml file.

Comment: Thanks! @SanjayGohil It's worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/etc/view.xml
```

path to override

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/etc/view.xml
```

example :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
                <width>30</width>
                <height>20</height>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
                <width>30</width>
                <height>20</height>
            </image>
            <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
                <width>110</width>
                <height>90</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Now applying changes you have to clear cache and var folder.